# Why Onclick function works only for the first iteration of the for each loop

Tags: php, html, jquery, foreach

I have a code where is display a set of images using foreach loop and when clicked it should return in the console the name of the image.

I tried the below code :

```
    <?php

    foreach ($gallery as $i) {

    ?>
    <img src="<?php echo "$i"; ?>" id="modal_img">

   <?php }
    ?>
```

the above code is the one that display the image through foreach loop iteration.

```
    $(function(){
       $("#modal_img").on("click",function(){
       var src = $(this).attr("src");
        console.log(src);
       })
     })
```

But with this code , every time I try, only the first image produces the result in the console , the other images when clicked gives no response in the console log. Can someone help me to resolve this. I have attached the image of screen below which shows the how the images are displayed.

[image]

Comment: You need to differentiate your images to get proper logs. Calling a common id would mostly pick the first of it's kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ID` is `unique`

Replace `ID` to `Class` `HTML` & `JS` Code

`<img src="<?php echo "$i"; ?>" class="modal_img">`

```
$(function(){
       $(".modal_img").on("click",function(){
       var src = $(this).attr("src");
        console.log(src);
       })
     })
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you cannot use the same id for more than once, use class or tag selectors

like this:
change it to class

```
    <img src="<?php echo "$i"; ?>" class="modal_img">
```

then

```
$(".modal_img").on('click', function(event){
 var src = $(this).attr("src");
    console.log(src);
   })
});
```